# Can I pass array of values as fnServerParams in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables to display data on my form. I have a requirement where I need to send multiple parameters to filter data.

Currently I am using:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span3'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span5'i><'span4'p>>",
        "bServerSide": true,                                      
        "sAjaxSource": //myurl,                                             
        "bProcessing": true,                                      
        "sPaginationType": true,                              
        "bSort": true,                                  
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            if (filtersAdded === "true") {
                aoData.push({ "name": "chk1", "value": true});
            }
        },                                           
        "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) { 
                // Do stuff with row data                
        },
        "bFilter": false,
        "bDestroy": true

    });
```

where chk1, chk2,.. are checkboxes and for simplicity sake, lets presume, user checked it as true. Now in my Code, I can easily retrieve chk1 value but my requirement is what if user chooses 3 or 4 checkboxes (I will have 7-8 checkboxes on my page)? I want to pass all these 3-4 choosen checkboxes value in an array to code(MVC).

What i am doing now is, getting all choosen checkboxes data in array as:

```
var filterarray = [];
filterarray .push({ "name": "chk1", "value": true});
filterarray .push({ "name": "chk2", "value": true});
```

Now how do i pass filterarray as a `fnServerParams` value? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've understood you correctly. Do you wanna send the information once or do you want to refresh the information as the user set/unset the checkboxes?

If you need to POST data for your ajax request you can use the code below:

```
 var oTable = $('#selector').dataTable( {
            "sAjaxSource": "your-url",
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                    aoData.push( {"name": "param1", "value": 1} );
                    aoData.push( {"name": "param2", "value": 2} );
                    $.ajax( {
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": aoData,
                            "success": function(result){
                                if (result.iTotalRecords == 0) {
                                        $("#datatable_unit_users").hide();
                                } else {
                                        $("#datatable_unit_users").show();
                                        fnCallback(result)
                                }
                            }

                    } );
            },
            ...
    )};
```

If you need to refresh your information you might use the API function fnReloadAjax (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api).

Hope it helps